# iterating over multiple dictionaries in a list

Tags: python

I have two lists of dictionaries `list_1` and `list_2`. I want to update each dictionary in `list_2` with the proper value(s) from the corresponding dictionary from `list_1` based on a match key values.

I am finding it difficult to iterate over dictionaries in a list. Any help would be appreciated.

INPUT:

```py
list_1 = [
    {'time': '2022-02-22T19:36:48.343000Z', 'name': 'oracle1', 'qid': '100172', 'utep': 'UEXC00345345'}, 
    {'time': '2022-02-22T19:36:48.343000Z', 'name': 'oracle2', 'qid': '105134', 'utep': 'UEXC1231231'}
]

list_2 = [
    {'time': '2021-03-02T23:31:46.495993Z', 'server_id': '100172', 'name': 'apache1'}, 
    {'time': '2021-03-02T23:31:46.516669Z', 'server_id': '100178', 'name': 'apache2'}
]
```

My code so far:

```py
for k in list1:
    for Q in list2:
        if (qid == server_id):
            list2.insert(list1[utep]
```

Comment: Are you searching for [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)? `[{**d1, **d2} for d1, d2 in zip(list1, list2)]`

Comment: I don't think this should have been closed as a `zip()` dupe. I think the questions is how to update a list of dictionaries based on a second list of dictionaries where there is a key match.

Comment: @JonSG, I am not the one who closed it but I'd definitely vote to close it with "Need details of clarity" reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want, but I think your code should be this:

```
for k in list1:
    for Q in list2:
        if k["qid"] == Q["server_id"]:
            Q["utep"] = k["utep"]
```